# Finding hte value of $1/(1^2)+1/(2^2)+1/(3^2)+\dots +1/(n^2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Sorry, my English isn't quite well.

Here is the problem.

When $n$ moves toward infinity
$$
1/(1^2)+1/(2^2)+1/(3^2)+\dots +1/(n^2)=?
$$

Any ideas?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

Comment: sorry, what does hte mean

Comment: what did you try? tried to read something before asking question?

Comment: In this case, "hte" means someone was sloppy writing out "the".